# how to show fa-icon in option tag in bootstrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, icons, styles

I am iterating options and want to show `check` and `times` icon with every option so I tried this code:

```
@foreach($findadminproducts as $a)
    <option value="{{ $a->id }}" >{{ $a->name }}
    @if ( $a->price == $product->price)
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">Matched</i>
    @else
        <i class="fal fa-times">Not Match</i>
    @endif
    </option>
@endforeach
```

In option I want if price is same show `check` icon else times but it does not show icon none of my icon is working if condition success then it shows match without icon on else condition it only shows "Not Match" without icon **I want match or not match with icon**

Comment: Provide enough context to understand your question, @Hamza Qureshi.
Are all of your icons are working but only this icon?

Comment: none of my icon is working if condition success then it shows match without icon on else condition it only shows unmatched without icon

Comment: Have you included `font-awesome` in your page?

Comment: no i did not included and also dont know how to include

Comment: now i have add <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js"></script> in @section('scripts') but it did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalid html option tag doesnot support nested tags so it is better for you u should use symbol as a text like ✓Matched